# how to change style component programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, controls, styles

I make a image into button control. Now i want to change that image using c# code.

```xml
 <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="r.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I want to Change MyImage Using C# Code.
thank`s for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`FindName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx):

```
((button.Template).FindName("MyImage", button) as Image).Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("..."));
```

Comment: Thank`s my bro. it is really helpful to me. again thank`s a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In your code-behind, say you want to change the picture to an image called `"s.png"`:

```
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"s.png", UriKind.Relative));
```